# Issues with running a LibGDX project

Tags: java, libgdx

I downloaded the libGDX setup jar file, I generated a project and imported it (to eclipse). Once I try to run the project eclipse outputs an error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip'.
Could not create service of type FileMetadataAccessor using NativeServices.createFileMetadataAccessor().
Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using Java 11. Try it with Java 8. The HTML module does not compile with a Java version greater then 8.

Comment: doesn't libGDX support Java 11?

Comment: And how can I switch to an older Java version in mac osx?

Comment: No, it uses also Language Level 6 for the sources

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 4.6 likely does not support [Java 11](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5120).

You can either upgrade to a newer version of Gradle or downgrade your JDK version.

I would recommend updating to Gradle 4.10.2 as it is the latest Gradle 4 variant (you can try Gradle 5 however it may introduce some breaking changes)

This can be done by running in the root of your project:

**Linux / MacOS:**

`./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=4.10.2`

**Windows:**

`gradle wrapper --gradle-version=4.10.2`

Comment: What tried what you said but...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.